# What's the point of subfolders in src folder

Tags: symfony

I need to create three folders in my project. In each of them I'd have to create a couple of subfolders containing proper classes.

So what is the point of creating a subfolder for all bundles in the SRC folder?

I mean, I'm dividing my project into Folder1Bundle, Folder2Bundle etc...So the folder structure would be:

src/ProjectName/Folder1Bundle
src/ProjectName/Folder2Bundle

etc.

And the src folder will contain only ProjectName folder...What's the point of creating big folders for bundle folders, instead of putting all bundles directly into the SRC folder?

Comment: I think the `ProjectName` in your case is for organization name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the [best practices for structuring bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html).

> A bundle is also a PHP namespace. The namespace must follow the technical interoperability standards for PHP 5.3 namespaces and class names: it starts with a vendor segment, followed by zero or more category segments, and it ends with the namespace short name, which must end with a Bundle suffix.

So the vendor name (ProjectName in your case) is for structuring namespace and get no conflicts with naming of other namespaces and symfony bundles.

Oh, and very important, the directory structure reflects your php namespace 1:1